# NullpointerException when opening a tabhost activity

Tags: android

I am working on an application where i moving from list menu to tabhost activity ,that is

Menu.class -> Recharge.class where 
Recharge.class is a TabActivity
having a tab named prepaid.class

I need to pass a string from menu.class to prepaid.class
in the below code i passed the string please find the bug in my code and help me

Menu.class

```
    if(s.equals("Recharge"))
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(menu.this,recharge.class);
            i.putExtra("app",app);
            startActivity(i);

        }
```

Recharge.class

```
Intent i = this.getIntent();            
    final String app=(String)i.getStringExtra("app");
   Resources res = getResources(); 
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; 
    Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, prepaid.class);
    intent.putExtra("app", app);

    //Prepaid
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("PREPAID").setIndicator("",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.prepaid))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabhost);
```

prepaid.class

```
Intent i=this.getIntent();
final String app=(String)i.getStringExtra("app");
```

**This is the error in log:**

```
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ezerecharge/com.example.ezerecharge.recharge}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ezerecharge/com.example.ezerecharge.prepaid}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ezerecharge/com.example.ezerecharge.prepaid}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1487)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:654)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:216)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.example.ezerecharge.recharge.onCreate(recharge.java:33)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     ... 11 more
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at com.example.ezerecharge.prepaid.<init>(prepaid.java:22)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
09-10 14:37:44.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
```

Comment: Just try like this in your `prepaid.class` - Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String app = bundle.getString(“app“);

Comment: Can you able to see your `Recharge.java` file?

Comment: no i am unable to view Recharge.java

Comment: Okay, then simply try there also with this - `Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); String app = bundle.getString(“app“);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling getIntent in the constructor. You cannot use it before the onCreate is called.

Move your intitialization code from prepaid in prepaid.onCreate.

And start your classes names by capital letters. please.